# File upload Base64 encoded string in PaperClip using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, paperclip, stringio

I have at base64 encoded string of a image file. I need to save it using Paper Clip

My Controller code is

```
 @driver = User.find(6)
 encoded_file = Base64.encode64(File.open('/pjt_path/public/test.jpg').read)
 decoded_file = Base64.decode64(encoded_file)

 @driver.profile_pic =  StringIO.open(decoded_file)
 @driver.save
```

In my user model

```
 has_attached_file :profile_pic, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => '/icon.jpg'
```

Currently the file is saved as a text file(stringio.txt). But when I change the extension to  JPG I can view it as image. How can I name the image correctly using StringIO.

I am having rails 3.2, ruby 1.9.2, paperclip 3.0.3

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I fixed the issue by using

```
encoded_file = Base64.encode64(File.open('/pjt_path/public/test.jpg').read)
decoded_file = Base64.decode64(params[:encoded_image])
begin
  file = Tempfile.new(['test', '.jpg']) 
  file.binmode
  file.write decoded_file
  file.close
  @user.profile_pic =  file
  if @user.save
    render :json => {:message => "Successfully uploaded the profile picture."}
  else
    render :json => {:message => "Failed to upload image"}
  end
ensure
  file.unlink
end
```

Comment: can u please post more of your code? I found it very intresting!

Comment: @EmSta - I have posted the complete code here. This code is added in my controller function. Please let me know what more code you needed

Comment: I opend an new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17336788/paperclip-upload-an-image-encoded-with-base64    Maybe you can help me @AmalKumarS

Comment: @EmSta - its showing "This question was voluntarily removed by its author."

Comment: on this version how can I handle multiple extention?

Comment: I am not sure, is this what you actually need.  From the file path given you can get the extention e.g.: /pjt_path/public/test.jpg  

Use this extension in the file = Tempfile.new(['test', '.jpg'])    section

Comment: File.extname("example.pdf/pjt_path/public/test.pdf")   will return the extension of the file

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the `:path`/`:url` option of `has_attached_file` and explicitly overriding the extension:

http://rdoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/ClassMethods#has_attached_file-instance_method

respectively

http://rdoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/Filesystem